# undefined method with has_one - belongs_to assocation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-one

```
class Activity < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :contract
  belongs_to :customer
  has_one    :expense
end

class Expense < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :activity
end
```

I get `undefined method expense' for nil:NilClass` when I try to create one `Expense` in the ExpensesController:

```
if !activity.try(:expense)
        activity.expense.create(ref: @current_date, year: session[:current_year], month: session[:current_month],
                                days:["1", "2"])
end
```

I suppose this is normal since the server is trying to call the `expense` from something that is `nil`.

The problem is that the original code is not mine. I had to add the association between `Activity` and `Expenses`. What should I do in order to create new `Expenses`?

EDIT: here's the full code of the `show` action of the `ExpensesController`

```
def show
if session[:current_month] == nil && session[:current_year] == nil
  session[:current_month] = params[:month]
  session[:current_year] = params[:year]
else
  if session[:current_month] != params[:month] || session[:current_year] != params[:year] 
    session[:current_month] = params[:month]
    session[:current_year] = params[:year]
  end
end

@calendar, @previous_month, @next_month, @month_name = get_calendar(session[:current_year], session[:current_month])
@current_date = @month_name + " " + session[:current_year]

# If expense does not exist, create one with current month
activity = Activity.where(month: params[:month], year: params[:year]).first
if activity.try(:expense)
  @nb_days = 0
  @calendar.each do |c|
      @nb_days += 1
  end
else
  activity.expense.create(ref: @current_date, year: session[:current_year], month: session[:current_month],
                            days:[""])
end   
@expense = activity.expense
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm reading this correctly, your `activity` variable is a null set.  I think the problem lies here:

```
activity = Activity.where(month: params[:month], year: params[:year]).first
```

This is not returning any records.